# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IClass>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<IClass>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface, ienumerable

I am getting the error in the title.

My repository method is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IItem>> GetItemsAsync()
{
    return await (from t in _Context.Items
    select t).ToListAsync();
}
```

I am calling it with:

```
data.Items = _FSRepository.GetItemsAsync();
```

data.Items is declared as:

```
public IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; set; }
```

Why is this not converting the Task IEnumerable Interface to the IEnumerable Interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to `await` the `GetItemsAsync` Otherwise it returns the signature of the method as is. `await` unwraps the `Task`

Comment: Wow, that was fail of me.  I can't believe I skipped over that.